# Curious about V$SESSION_LONGOPS output

Tags: oracle

I am curious about something, I was trying to find any long running queries currently running on my Oracle database.

The Query:

```
SELECT username,sid, serial#,
     TO_CHAR(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,'HH24:MI:SS') AS curr,
     TO_CHAR(start_time,'HH24:MI:SS') AS logon,
     (sysdate - start_time)*24*60 AS mins
FROM V$SESSION_LONGOPS
WHERE    username is not NULL
AND (SYSDATE - start_time)*24*60 > 1 ;
```

The output:

```
USERNAME SID   SERIAL#  CURR         LOGON       MINS
user     1999   23457   15:53:59    13:58:10    4435.81666666667
user     581    7549    15:53:59    15:57:10    4316.81666666667
user    1999    31343   15:53:59    16:58:10    4255.81666666667
```

Based on the info above is that telling me I have several queries running for days?

I am new to Oracle, mostly MySQL but i know in MySQL this is not a good thing.

If someone could tell me what I am seeing that would be great.

Comment: What does `time_remaining` and `last_update_time` show?  My first guess would be that those are rows for operations that completed long ago or for processes that were killed and didn't clean up after themselves properly.

Comment: Please post the output of this query `select sid, opname, message from v$session_longops`. In this query the `OPNAME` denotes the operation name like `TABLE SCAN`, `Gather Table Partition Statistics` etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Long running queries may show up in `V$SESSION_LONGOPS`, but it is far from giving a complete overview. Only a few specific built-in operations are logged here, for example full table scan, index fast full scan, hash join, sorts and some other.

`V$SESSION_LONGOPS` shows not only the current long operations, but a history as well. The number of entries retained is 500, according to [V$Session_longops Have Limited Records Of 500 (Doc ID 783721.1)](https://support.oracle.com/epmos/faces/DocContentDisplay?id=783721.1) This is per instance by the way.

For example, I have 480 entries, the first one is almost a week old:

```
SQL> select sysdate, min(last_update_time), count(*) from gv$session_longops;

SYSDATE    MIN(LAST_U   COUNT(*)
---------- ---------- ----------
2016-12-04 2016-11-28        480
```

479 of them is not related to any current session (the remaining one I created artificially just to see a difference).

```
SQL> select count(*) from gv$session_longops 
     where (inst_id, sid, serial#) not in (select inst_id, sid, serial# from gv$session);

  COUNT(*)
----------
       479
```

On a 2-node cluster:

```
SQL> select inst_id, sysdate, min(last_update_time), count(*)
     from gv$session_longops group by inst_id;

   INST_ID SYSDATE   MIN(LAST_   COUNT(*)
---------- --------- --------- ----------
         1 04-DEC-16 27-NOV-16        453
         2 04-DEC-16 02-DEC-16        473
```

View other columns as well, for example `opname` and `last_update_time` as suggested. Also, join to `gv$session` to find which entries are current.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely not queries but system operations, e.g. gather statistics.
Probably nothing to worry about.

[V$SESSION_LONGOPS](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28320/dynviews_3021.htm#REFRN30227)

> V$SESSION_LONGOPS displays the status of various operations that run
>   for longer than 6 seconds (in absolute time). These operations
>   currently include many backup and recovery functions, statistics
>   gathering, and query execution, and more operations are added for
>   every Oracle release.

Just to verify, check `opname` and `target_desc`.